# How to read latest SPSS .por file format

Tags: file, format, spss

Does anyone know the format of SPSS .por files?  I am maintaining a utility that reads .por files.  It worked perfectly up until v12 of SPSS.  It no longer reads .por files created with the latest version of SPSS (v19).  What has changed in the .por file format?  Or how can I find out how to read these .por files?

Comment: What does your utility do with the .por file?
SPSS has changed significantly since V12, IBM have changed a lot since they purchased the company and most formats from older versions clash with the new versions (i.e. you can't use the new syntax with the old program, you can't read the old Output documents with the new program etc.)

Answer (score 0):

They are fixed ASCII records of 80 characters each. The first few lines are header data, the rest are the actual data in base-30 format.

You use the IMPORT command in SPSS to read them in.